# Execute a terminal command without saving it to .bash_history on OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal, history

[This site](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1512/execute-a-command-without-saving-it-in-the-history) says that on Linux you can add a `space` before a terminal command to keep it out of `.bash_history`.

**This does not seem to work for Mac OS X. Does anyone know of a way to execute a single command on the Terminal without saving it to history?**

I don't want to clear the history.

[image]

Comment: adding a ` ` (space) before a terminal command will *not* keep it out of the history

Comment: @warren No, it does. You just have to enable the feature in bash.

Comment: @firebat - right: but since it's something you *have* to enable, it may or may not work *everywhere* :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add the following line to ~/.bashrc

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
```

Then `source ~/.bashrc` to refresh the settings

This should enable that feature in bash. If it doesn't work, you might have to add it to ~/.bash_profile instead of ~/.bashrc since OS X loads them a bit differently than linux I think.

Comment: How can I use two options with that? I want to use `export HISTCONTROL=erasedups,ignorespace` but I think that syntax does not work...

Comment: `export HISTCONTROL=erasedups:ignorespace`

Comment: But i think it's actually `export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace`

Comment: The "ignoredups" setting ignores repeated lines. Typing "ls" twenty times in a row only ends up with one of them in history. However, typing "ls" and then "ps" and then "ls" again will store "ls" and "ps" every time - unless you have bash 3 and set "erasedups". If that's set, no duplicates get entered in bash history at all. - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop-array/

Comment: Adding to .bash_profile works.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. [I have tried both](https://superuser.com/q/1202464/114642) `export HISTCONTROL=erasedups:ignorespace` and `export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace` and even `export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignoreboth`. But what I get is a single entry for each *session* rather than across sessions: i.e., if a command is already in `.bash_history` at the start of a session, and it's typed again, it will be added to history (though only once for that session). How do I ensure that a command that's already in `.bash_history when I launch Terminal isn't added if it's entered again?

Comment: It seems that `.bashrc` is not used (OSX 10.13.5) but `.bash_profile` is.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not concerned about keeping the session active, this may work:

```
kill -9 $$
```

It will kill the current session instead of logging-out, which [theoretically] means your history will not be saved.