# Prevent command already saved in Bash history from being added to history on macOS

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, history

I'd like to prevent commands that are already present in `.bash_history` on macOS from being added again if reentered in Terminal (usually by typing the first few characters and scanning back in history).

[I have tried](https://superuser.com/a/324881/114642)

- `export HISTCONTROL=erasedups:ignorespace`
- `export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace`

and even

- `export HISTCONTROL=erasedups: ignoreboth`

But what I get is a single entry for each *session* rather than across sessions: i.e., if a command is already in `.bash_history` at the start of a session, and it's typed again, it will be added to history (though only once for that session). How do I ensure that a command that's already in `.bash_history when I launch Terminal isn't added if it's entered again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable repeated items in bash history](https://superuser.com/questions/739107/disable-repeated-items-in-bash-history)